# Why can't I get the API data using Django again?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a web app I'm developing locally, part of the app uses cryptocompare.

Contrarily to my previous experience on using API in Django(because previously I've been able to get data from cryptocomapare through there API), I couldn't even print the data to the console, not to talk of template.

I have even checked different other means of doing this in python on YouTube and blogs, but I don't seem to miss anything too (at least as far as I'm concerned, but technically speaking something is wrong).

I have the app in the `settings/installed-app`.

I have my API key linked accordingly (at least as far as I can understand).

I have done the following to create the app in Django:

The crypto code is like this for Django:

```python
import requests

def cryptos(request):
    api_rqt = requests.get(
        'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN&api_key={my-app-key)')
    api = json.loads(api_rqt.content)
    print(api_rqt)
    context = {'api': api}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

```html
<div>
{% for api in api.Data%}
    <h4><a href="">{{api.title}}</a></h4>
    <h5>By <a href=""></a> <label>|</label> <i>{{api.published_on}}</i></h5>
    <p>{{api.body}}</p>
    <a href="{{api.url}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary"> Read More ...</a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I expect the output to show me news summary from cryptocompare but nothing is shown. And my Django server is running very well.

I received some exception message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[27/Aug/2019 10:46:30] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53817)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\python-web-works\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\python-web-works\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\python-web-works\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\python-web-works\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "c:\users\timilehin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Inspect the `api_rqt` and `api` variables in your view (BTW you should use `api_rqt.json()` instead of `json.loads(api_rqt.content)`) and edit your post to add what they look like.

Comment: Do you get any Exceptions?

Comment: i tried your code in python terminal and I am getting data. Can you tell how you are calling this view? can you post your urls.py?

Comment: @PauloScardine yes I do and I have updated the question to include the exception message. Pardon me please I don't know how to format in a better form

Comment: @NalinDobhal the url is urlpatterns = [ path('', views.cryptos, name='cryptos'), ]

Comment: @NalinDobhal 
Please maybe it will also help you to quickly guide me more by knowing that 'home.html' is created in the templates/home.html which is in the project directory, and inside setting's template, ['templates'] has been set, in short I have other things coming to the home page just the API is giving me issue please

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've tried your suggestion nothing seems to change bro.

Comment: @toppylawz in case it wasn't clear enough, my suggestion wasn't supposed to fix anything but to provide useful debugging informations. if you want help, do what I said and edit your post to include the results. But given the exceptions messages you posted, you obviously have another issue, which FWIW contradicts your statement that "your Django server is running very well". Oh and yes: I'm not your "bro".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers what I meant by  "my Django server is running very well " was that even at that, I can access everything from the front-end, I thought if there's an error in Django server I wouldn't be able to access the front end so that's how I thought Django works(well I'm a novice developer but this will be my 8th app in Django), and about my previous comment to you, I'm only trying to be respectful(this is one of our culture here), so if I offended you unknowingly well I am sorry.

Comment: @toppylawz The fact that the server process is running only means you have no syntax error and no exception happening at the modules top-level. Errors in functions/methods will only be raised when those functions/methods are actually executed. Which FWIW is how _python_ works (not specifically Django).

Comment: @toppylawz wrt/ the "bro" thing: yes, dealing with cultural differences is not always that easy (I only know too well - we frenchies don't have much of this american "be kind" culture and can be perceived as quite harsh - or worse - by US standard when, as far as we're concerned, we just stated something obvious that no one in his own mind would consider "offensive"...) IOW, no offense taken - but you (and me too FWIW) should try to remember that cultural differences exist  ;-)

Comment: @PauloScardine Thanks a lot, I made a mistake with how I have been calling my url in the browser, and thanks to everyone that helped me in one way or the other( at least by trying to guide me on what might be wrong) so the issue is solved. Very funny I've been battling with this for like 3 days. Special thanks  brunodesthuilliers I really appreciate your understanding.

Comment: @toppylawz Welcome to Stackoverflow - you are right, posting the error messages/stack traces helps a lot. Good questions are 90% of the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If I look at that data, then what you actually want to pass to the html template is :

```
context = {'api': api['Data']}
```

This is then a list of dictionaries that you can iterate over using:

```
{% for dict in api %}
```

You can then find the fields you want.

Alternatively, look at flattening the dictionaries to only the fields you want before passing everything as the context.